# Can't access App Store - email invalid

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I accidentally created my Apple ID with the email address ending ".con" not ".com". I've changed it on My Apple ID and can now log in on iCloud and the computer fine, but can't log in to the App Store on my iPhone as it still has my email as .con there and there's no option to change it, only to enter a password.

I tried:

1. Logging out of iCloud and back in.
2. The main suggestion I've found online is to change my Apple ID back to .con, log in to the App Store and then log out again, but I can't as My Apple ID won't accept .con as a valid email (a bit bizarrely given it let me set up the account with that in the first place without flagging an error...).

I've run out of ideas as to how to get into the App Store. Anyone have any ideas? This one's got me stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > iTunes and App Store and click the email address at the top of the page.  You will get a popup with an options to signout.  Choose that, then you will be able to change it.